# Configure GeoNetwork to work with Jetty

Tags: installation, geonetwork, jetty

I am trying to get GeoNetwork to work  on my Windows Server 2016 machine, I installed geonetwork 2.10.4. but when I open http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/ 404 page not found error has shown.

On my server GeoServer is also working http://localhost:8080/.

I'm very new in this job. How could I start GeoNetwork?

This is my jetty/geonetwork log file

```
2019-09-27 15:17:41,608 INFO  [jeeves] - Upload directory is: C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\./data/tmp/
2019-09-27 15:17:41,623 WARN  [jeeves.dbmspool] - Using transaction isolation setting READ_COMMITTED
2019-09-27 15:17:50,332 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service csw already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,410 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service xml.metadata.insert already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,410 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service xml.metadata.delete already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,410 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service xml.relation.get already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,410 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service xml.relation.insert already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,410 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Service xml.relation.delete already exist, re-register it.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,489 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Initializing GeoNetwork 2.10.4-0.SNAPSHOT ...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,504 WARN  [geonetwork.data.directory] -    - Data directory initialization: null
2019-09-27 15:17:50,504 WARN  [geonetwork.data.directory] -     - Data directory properties is not set. Use geonetwork.dir or geonetwork.dir properties.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,504 WARN  [geonetwork.data.directory] -     - Data directory provided could not be used. Using default location: C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\
2019-09-27 15:17:50,520 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Data directory: C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\
2019-09-27 15:17:50,520 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - jeeves.xml.catalog.files property set to C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\oasis-catalog.xml;C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schemaplugin-uri-catalog.xml
2019-09-27 15:17:50,520 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - jeeves.xml.catalog.blankxslfile property set to C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\xsl\blanks.xsl
2019-09-27 15:17:50,520 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Overriding mime-mappings property (was set to ..\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\mime-types.properties)
2019-09-27 15:17:50,520 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - mime-mappings property set to C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\mime-types.properties
2019-09-27 15:17:50,723 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Database connection on jdbc:h2:geonetwork;LOCK_TIMEOUT=20000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=TRUE ...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,723 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -       Found an existing GeoNetwork database.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,739 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Thread Pool...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,739 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Setting manager...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,785 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Migration ...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,785 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -       Webapp   version:2.10.4-0 subversion:SNAPSHOT
2019-09-27 15:17:50,785 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -       Database version:2.10.4 subversion:0
2019-09-27 15:17:50,785 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -       Webapp version = Database version, no migration task to apply.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,785 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Z39.50...
2019-09-27 15:17:50,832 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -      Repositories file built from template.
2019-09-27 15:17:50,832 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@24955144: startup date [Fri Sep 27 15:17:50 GMT+02:00 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-09-27 15:17:50,848 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [JZkitApplicationContext.xml]
2019-09-27 15:17:51,520 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5ca8bd01: defining beans [JZKitZ3950PluginMetadata,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,QB-CQL,org.jzkit.recordbuilder.iso2709,org.jzkit.recordbuilder.xml,org.jzkit.recordbuilder.string,messageSource,ContextGateway,OIDRegister,Z3950Listener,JZKit2SearchBackend,JZKitConfig,ProfileService,TransformationService,RecordBuilderService,StatelessQueryService,SearchSession,SearchSessionFactory,RPNToInternalRules,InternalToType1ConversionRules,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-09-27 15:17:52,465 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -      Server is Enabled.
2019-09-27 15:17:52,465 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Schema manager...
2019-09-27 15:17:52,481 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -            - Schema plugins directory: C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schema_plugins
2019-09-27 15:17:52,481 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -            - Schema Catalog File     : C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schemaplugin-uri-catalog.xml
2019-09-27 15:17:52,903 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - Cannot resolve http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd: will append last component to current path (not sure it will help though!)
2019-09-27 15:17:53,512 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: gco:Record is a global element without a type - assuming a string
2019-09-27 15:17:53,997 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: gco:Record is a global element without a type - assuming a string
2019-09-27 15:17:54,012 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: schema-substitutions.xml has wiped out XSD substitution list for gml:VerticalDatum
2019-09-27 15:17:54,012 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: schema-substitutions.xml has wiped out XSD substitution list for gml:CoordinateSystemAxis
2019-09-27 15:17:54,012 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: schema-substitutions.xml has wiped out XSD substitution list for gml:VerticalCS
2019-09-27 15:17:54,028 WARN  [geonetwork.schemamanager] - WARNING: schema-substitutions.xml has wiped out XSD substitution list for gml:CoordinateSystemAxis
2019-09-27 15:17:56,267 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Search...
2019-09-27 15:17:56,282 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Log spatial object: false
2019-09-27 15:17:56,282 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Log in asynch mode: true
2019-09-27 15:17:56,329 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Lucene configuration is:
2019-09-27 15:17:56,329 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Lucene configuration:
 * Version: LUCENE_36
 * RAMBufferSize: 48.0
 * MergeFactor: 10
 * Default analyzer: org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer
 * Field analyzers: {operatesOn=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, hasfeaturecat=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, subject=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, hassource=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, _groupPublished=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, _source=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, _uuid=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, _cat=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, keyword=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, parentUuid=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, inspirerelated=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, operatesOnIdentifier=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer}
 * Field search analyzers: {subject=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, hassource=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, _groupPublished=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, _uuid=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, parentUuid=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, operatesOn=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, hasfeaturecat=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer, _source=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, _cat=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, keyword=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, inspirerelated=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, operatesOnIdentifier=org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.GeoNetworkAnalyzer}
 * Field boost factor: {_isTemplate=0.0, _owner=0.0, _op0=0.0, _op1=0.0, _dummy=0.0, _op2=0.0}
 * Boost document class: null
 * Tokenized fields: [specificationTitle, subject, altTitle, keywordType, levelName, abstract, title, any]
 * Numeric fields: [eastBL, southBL, northBL, westBL, denominator]
 * Dump fields: {serviceType=serviceType, _isPublishedToAll=isPublishedToAll, _edit=edit, _owner=owner, responsibleParty=responsibleParty, link=link, _indexingError=idxError, language=language, _defaultTitle=defaultTitle, type=type, datasetLang=datasetLang, _isHarvested=isHarvested, _displayOrder=displayOrder, _selected=selected, _docLocale=docLocale, conditionApplyingToAccessAndUse=Constraints, _popularity=popularity, _userinfo=userinfo, _download=download, keyword=keyword, credit=credit, _indexingErrorMsg=idxMsg, _valid_xsd=valid_xsd, _notify=notify, _featured=featured, otherConstr=Constraints, image=image, _valid_schematron-rules-iso=valid_schematron-rules-iso, _ownername=ownername, _valid_schematron-rules-geonetwork=valid_schematron-rules-geonetwork, _title=title, abstract=abstract, _status=status, accessConstr=Constraints, parentUuid=parentId, _isTemplate=isTemplate, _valid_schematron-rules-inspire=valid_schematron-rules-inspire, classif=SecurityConstraints, _view=view, _dynamic=dynamic, _valid=valid, spatialRepresentationType=spatialRepresentationType, _rating=rating, _source=source, _cat=category, _locale=_locale, geoBox=geoBox}
 * Search boost query: null
 * Score: 
  * trackDocScores: false 
  * trackMaxScore: false 
  * docsScoredInOrder: false 
Taxonomy configuration: [hits, results_with_summary, titles, results]
  * type: hits
{serviceType=Field: serviceType name:serviceType    max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, inspiretheme=Field: inspiretheme name:inspireTheme   max:35  sort byVALUE    sort order:ASCENDIND, orgName=Field: orgName    name:orgName    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, spatialRepresentationType=Field: spatialRepresentationType   name:spatialRepresentationType  max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, metadataPOC=Field: metadataPOC   name:metadataPOC    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, keyword=Field: keyword   name:keyword    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, type=Field: type name:type   max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, createDateYear=Field: createDateYear name:createDateYear max:40  sort byVALUE    sort order:DESCENDING, denominator=Field: denominator   name:denominator    max:10  sort byNUMVALUE sort order:DESCENDING}  * type: results_with_summary
{serviceType=Field: serviceType name:serviceType    max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, inspiretheme=Field: inspiretheme name:inspireTheme   max:35  sort byVALUE    sort order:ASCENDIND, orgName=Field: orgName    name:orgName    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, spatialRepresentationType=Field: spatialRepresentationType   name:spatialRepresentationType  max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, metadataPOC=Field: metadataPOC   name:metadataPOC    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, keyword=Field: keyword   name:keyword    max:15  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, type=Field: type name:type   max:10  sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING, createDateYear=Field: createDateYear name:createDateYear max:40  sort byCOUNT    sort order:ASCENDIND, denominator=Field: denominator    name:denominator    max:20  sort byVALUE    sort order:ASCENDIND}  * type: titles
{title=Field: title name:title  max:100 sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING}  * type: results
{keyword=Field: keyword name:keyword    max:100 sort byCOUNT    sort order:DESCENDING}
2019-09-27 15:17:56,329 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Using shapefile C:\geonetwork-2.10.4\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\index\spatialindex.shp
2019-09-27 15:17:57,376 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - NOTE: Using shapefile for spatial index, this can be slow for larger catalogs
2019-09-27 15:17:58,032 WARN  [geonetwork.lucene] - Stopwords file with incorrect ISO 639-2 language as filename: README
2019-09-27 15:17:59,168 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Access manager...
2019-09-27 15:17:59,168 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Xml serializer and Data manager...
2019-09-27 15:18:00,968 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Thesaurus...
2019-09-27 15:18:00,983 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Catalogue services for the web...
2019-09-27 15:18:01,030 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Open Archive Initiative (OAI-PMH) server...
2019-09-27 15:18:01,796 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Metadata notifier ...
2019-09-27 15:18:01,796 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Metadata notifier ...
2019-09-27 15:18:01,796 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] - Site ID is : aec5063c-130f-476a-a8b0-6a7c2000171c
2019-09-27 15:18:01,796 INFO  [jeeves.apphand] -   - Harvest manager...
```

Comment: solved geoserver is also working on port 8080 is changing geoserver port and it is working now.